# filter cursor adapter listview 3 field at the same time

Tags: android, listview, filter, android-cursoradapter

I filter a listview populated with a cursor adapter, now I want filter the list using 3 different fields at the same time.

To better Explain:
I have 3 spinner, by theese I select the 3 strings to filter the list, but I don't know how pass all 3 strings to filter the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either encode the 3 strings into one (for example JSON, as it's built in .. see org.json package), or forget the filtering api and repopulate the list each time by hand...

Comment: I think that too. But how can I manage that string in filter(string) method?